# Program for converting an array of bytes to hexadecimal

Tags: c, formatting

I have written a program that outputs the hexadecimal representation of an array of bytes. The program works just fine, and I am confident (thanks to valgrind) that I don't have any memory leaks. However, I am not so confident I am doing this the simplest, nor most readable way. It seems to me I have written a lot of code for a small task.

I am looking for general feedback, including code style, types, variable naming, usage of malloc, and simpler ways of appending a char array to a string, possibly avoiding `sprintf`.

The program was written to exercise storing a hexadecimal representation of a byte array in a string, not printing it out directly using `printf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const unsigned char bytearr[] = { 0x0b, 0x34, 0x33, 0x32 };
    const int hexlen = 2; // outputting hex value with leading zero
    const int outstrlen = sizeof(bytearr) * sizeof(char) * sizeof(bytearr[0]) * hexlen;

    char *outstr;
    if ((outstr = malloc(outstrlen + 1)) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero(outstr, outstrlen + 1);

    int i;
    char tmp[hexlen + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(bytearr) / sizeof(bytearr[0])); i++) {
        sprintf(tmp, "%.2x", bytearr[i]);
        strcat(outstr, tmp);
    }

    printf("Hexadecimal string:\n%s\n", outstr);

    free(outstr);

    return 0;
}
```

For what it's worth, after this review, my program [ended up like this](https://gist.github.com/stigok/1737e05ef2c02cb03e7e584a8145b77e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't mix signed and unsigned

GCC warns about

```
192329.c:8:79: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
     const int outstrlen = sizeof(bytearr) * sizeof(char) * sizeof(bytearr[0]) * hexlen;
                                                                               ^
192329.c:8:27: warning: conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
     const int outstrlen = sizeof(bytearr) * sizeof(char) * sizeof(bytearr[0]) * hexlen;
                           ^~~~~~
192329.c:11:36: warning: conversion to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
     if ((outstr = malloc(outstrlen + 1)) == NULL) {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~^~~
192329.c:19:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
     for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(bytearr) / sizeof(bytearr[0])); i++) {
                   ^
```

These are easily fixed by changing `outstrlen`, `hexlen` and `i` to unsigned types (ideally `size_t` in all cases).

## Prefer `memset()` over `bzero()`

The standard library function to initialize memory is `memset()`; `bzero()` is a common extension, but less portable.  It turns out we don't need it anyway, as we will overwrite that initialization with our output - no need to fill with zeros first (if we really do want to do that, consider using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`).  We just need `outstr[0] = 0;` so we start with an empty string.

## Size computation

`sizeof (char)` is always 1, because `sizeof` measures in units of `char`.  And there seems to be more storage computed than we need - we actually just require twice the input length plus the terminating NUL.

## Error checking

It's good that you remembered to check your allocation didn't return NULL.  I'd tidy that up to assign then test, like this:

```
char *outstr = malloc(outstrlen);
if (!outstr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Notice that the error message now goes to the standard error stream, and ends in a newline.  And I prefer to `return` from `main()` rather than calling `exit()`.

## Print directly into the output

Instead of printing into a `tmp` array, write the characters directly into the output buffer.  We know the position for index `i` is `outstr + hexlen * i`, so we can simply

```
for (size_t i = 0;  i < sizeof bytearr / sizeof bytearr[0];  ++i) {
    sprintf(outstr + hexlen * i, "%.2x", bytearr[i]);
}
```

Note that each `sprintf` overwrites the final NULL of the previous.

One technique that works is to declare a pointer for the current write position, then at each iteration add the number of characters printed:

```
char *p = outstr;
for (size_t i = 0;  i < sizeof bytearr / sizeof bytearr[0];  ++i) {
    p += sprintf(p, "%0*hhx", (int)hexlen, bytearr[i]);
}
```

## Consider writing a function

It's good to separate the reusable part of your code from the setup and output instructions.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Returns a string representation of _length_ bytes beginning at
   _array_.  The caller has responsibility to release the string,
   using _free()_.  If the string could not be allocated, returns a
   null pointer instead. */
char *to_hex_string(const unsigned char *array, size_t length)
{
    char *outstr = malloc(2*length + 1);
    if (!outstr) return outstr;

    char *p = outstr;
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < length;  ++i) {
        p += sprintf(p, "%02hhx", array[i]);
    }

    return outstr;
}

int main() {
    const unsigned char bytearr[] = { 0x0b, 0x34, 0x33, 0x32 };

    char *outstr = to_hex_string(bytearr, sizeof bytearr);
    if (!outstr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Hexadecimal string:\n%s\n", outstr);

    free(outstr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback! Since we've concluded we already know the size of the byte arrays elements, is it also *okay* to drop `sizeof bytearr / sizeof bytearr[0]` in the `for` loop and simply use `i < sizeof bytearr`? Correct me if I'm wrong as I am now interpreting the line of `char *p = outstr;`  as exactly the way to avoid being *Shlemiel The Painter* in the `sprintf` example.

Comment: I am compiling with `gcc -fverbose-asm -Wall -g -O0 -o hexstr hexstr.c`, and I did not get any such errors about the lack of `size_t`. Care to share some more parameters I could use?

Comment: I recommend adding `-Wextra` as a minimum.  Other warnings I usually enable are `-Wwrite-strings  -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds      -Wconversion`, but there's one I usually disable: `-Wno-parentheses`

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to drop the division by `sizeof bytearr[0]` because that must be 1 (though if you're writing code where the type of array might change, that's a good safety feature to keep; in this case, changing the type would also necessitate a change to the `printf` and to `hex_len`, so it's probably so tightly embedded that we needn't do so).  And yes, `char *p` is exactly the mechanism to take the paint bucket with us as the work moves.

Answer (score 5):

Well, aside from the fact that you could just reduce the program to outputting a single string-literal, let's look at it:

1. Excellent code-formatting. That's far too rare.
2. The calculation for `outstrlen` is all kinds of bent. Both middle factors don't make any sense.

   ```
   sizeof(bytearr) * sizeof(char)   * sizeof(bytearr[0]) * hexlen
   size_in_bytes   * bytes_per_byte * bytes_per_byte     * digits_per_byte
   ```
3. Just to be "safe", you zero `outstr` before overwriting it...
   That isn't safe, that's redundant.
4. There's no good reason to use [`bzero()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero) and make your program unportable. Just use [`memset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) if you must.
5. Why do you print into a temporary buffer, only to append it to the output-string?

   1. Print directly into the final destination. No need for an intermediate.
   2. If you build a string bit by bit, don't be [Shlemiel The Painter](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter). No need to make a linear algorithm quadratic.
6. As you immediately exit the program, freeing memory is just busy-work. Still, as I'm not sure what you are trying to learn there, it might be excused.
7. As an aside, `return 0;` is implicit for `main()` in C99+ and C++. Not sure you that's really relevant, but here you go.

Equivalent program (C99+ or C++):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hexadecimal string:\n0b343332\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. My primary goal here was to save the hexadecimals to a string. Not to print them out. The `malloc()` is there because I thought I *should*. The `free()` is there because the `malloc()` is there.

Comment: And now I understand that the heap is normally freed upon exit by the operating system, hence making the `free()` redundant, too, in this specific example.